# How do you perform floating point arithmetic on two floating point numbers?

Tags: math, floating-point

Suppose I wanted to add, subtract, and/or multiply the following two floating point numbers that follow the format:

> 1 bit sign
>
> 3 bit exponent (bias 3)
>
> 6 bit mantissa

Can someone briefly explain how I would do that?  I've tried searching online for helpful resources, but I haven't been able to find anything too intuitive.  However, I know the procedure is generally supposed to be very simple.  As an example, here are two numbers that I'd like to perform the three operations on:

> 0 110 010001
>
> 1 010 010000

Comment: What sources did you find, what did you find hard to understand?

Comment: You are mistaken when you say that "the procedure is generally supposed to be very simple". It's not rocket science, but it's not tic-tac-toe either. More complicated than implementing a balanced binary B-tree, for instance.

Answer (score 3):

To start, take the significand encoding and prefix it with a “1.”, and write the result with the sign determined by the sign bit. So, for your example numbers, we have:

```
+1.010001
-1.010000
```

However, these have different scales, because they have different exponents. The exponent of the second one is four less than the first one (010<sub>2</sub> compared to 110<sub>2</sub>). So shift it right by four bits:

```
+1.010001
- .0001010000
```

Now both significands have the same scale (exponent 110<sub>2</sub>), so we can perform normal arithmetic, in binary:

```
+1.010001
- .0001010000
_____________
+1.0011000000
```

Next, round the significand to the available bits (seven). In this case, the trailing bits are zero, so the rounding does not change anything:

```
+1.001100
```

At this point, we could have a significand that needed more shifting, if it were greater than 2 (10<sub>2</sub>) or less than 1. However, this significand is just where we want it, between 1 and 2. So we can keep the exponent as is (110<sub>2</sub>).

Convert the sign back to a bit, take the leading “1.” off the significand, and put the bits together:

```
0 110 001100
```

Exceptions would arise if the number overflowed or underflowed the normal exponent range, but those did not happen here.